Expected Ratio of Boys to Girls?
Assume that a couple keeps having children until they have $2$ consecutive girl children. What is the expected ratio of boys to girls? Assume that probability of having a girl child is $p$.
I tried assuming that the expected ratio is $r$. And then based on assuming first few children being either $B$, $GB$ or $GG$, I tried to find a recurrence relation for $r$. But the problem is : we are trying to calculate the expected value of ratio of two random variables which is making it difficult. I asked Chatgpt to do the simulation and the result it gave me for $P = 0.5$ is around $0.84$
P.S: Some people are telling me to not use chatgpt for simulation. Actually, I had verified the code that chatgpt used for simulation and it is an easy programme. It was doing simulation correctly

I asked ChatGPT to calculate $3^5$ and it answered $243$. Then I asked ChatGPT to calculate $2^5$ and again it answered $243$. Never use ChatGPT or any A.I. bot to perform calculations! :-)

I must've misunderstood, but if you're going to stop after the 2nd girl child, the BOY:GIRL ratio for $n$ children = $\frac{n - 2}{2}$. That's for $p = 0.5$

The couple is going to stop when they have 2 consecutive girl child and not just 2 girl child

The twist here is that the expected ratio of boys to girls over a whole population of such families is just $(1-p)/p$. But the expected per-family ratio is very different.

ChatGPT repeats answers that it has found on the internet, whether these answers are right or wrong.  If someone wrote 3^5 =243 it will repeat that. If someone wrote 2^5 = 243 then it repeats that. If it has never read answer it makes up sh**.

In ChatGPT's defense, it is capable of writing programs which can do calculations reliably, and execute them. Of course, you do need to proofread the program to ensure it really does what it says, which it seems OP did.

For P(girl) = P(boy) = 0.5, this $\frac{boys}{girls} = \frac{boys}{boys + 2}$ and total number of children = $boys + boys + 2 = 2(boys + 1)$

"Expected ratio of boys to girls" is $\mathbb E[\frac{b}{g}]$, which is not equal to $\frac{\mathbb E[b]}{\mathbb E[g]}$.

Corrected an analytical error in Addendum-1.

Added an Addendum-1 to the end of my answer to respond to the comment of user5001880.

Added an Addendum at the end of this answer to complete the problem.

I am assuming that when there are $~b~$ boys and $~a~$ girls, that the pertinent ratio is $~\dfrac{b}{a}.$
Let $~q = 1-p \implies ~$ probability of a boy is $~q.$
For $~a \geq 2, ~b \geq 1,~$ let $~E(a,b)~$ denote the event that there were $~a~$ girls and $~b~$ boys born, where the first occurrence of $~2~$ consecutive girls was on the last $~2~$ children born.
Let $~f(a,b)~$ denote the probability that event $~E(a,b)~$ occurred.
Then $~f(a,b) = p^a ~q^b \times ~$ the number of satisfying ways that the $~a~$ girls and $~b~$ boys could be distributed.
The last $~3~$ children born must have specifically been : boy, girl, girl.  The exception is when there were only two children born, both girls.
So, consider the first $~(a + b - 3)~$ children born, by considering the following tableau:
- girl - - girl - girl - - girl - 

In the above tableau, you have (in effect) $~(a-2)~$ girls born among the first $~(a + b - 3)~$ children.  Further, these $~(a - 2)~$ girls create $~(a - 1)~$ islands of boys.
Then, reading these islands from left to right, let $~x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_{a-1}~$ denote the respective sizes of these islands.
Then, the number of satisfying distributions of the first $~(a + b - 3)~$ births equals the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{a-1} = b - 1.~$ 
This is because there is exactly one boy among the last three children.

$x_1, ~x_{a-1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_2, ~x_3, ~\cdots, ~x_{a-2} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$ 
This is because you can't have two consecutive girls among the first $~(a + b - 3)~$ births.


Clearly, you must have $~(b-1) \geq (a-3) \implies b \geq (a - 2).$
So, by Stars and Bars theory, which is also discussed here, the number of satisfying distributions is
$$\binom{[b-1] - [a - 3] + [a-2]}{a-2} = \binom{b}{a-2}.$$
So, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{a = 2}^\infty \left[ ~\sum_{b = a-2}^\infty p^a ~q^b ~\binom{b}{a-2} ~\frac{b}{a} ~\right]. \tag1 $$

$\underline{\text{Addendum - Final Computation / Simplification}}$
The expression in (1) above can be simplified by setting
$$g(a) = \sum_{b = a-2}^\infty p^a ~q^b ~\binom{b}{a-2} ~\frac{b}{a},$$
so that the expression in (1) above becomes
$$\sum_{a=2}^\infty g(a).$$
To do this, I will use the following identities:

$\displaystyle b \times \binom{b}{a-2} = \left[ ~(a-1) ~\binom{b+1}{a-1} ~\right] - \binom{b}{a-2}.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} ~: ~-1 < x < 1.$


So,
$$g(a) = \frac{p^a}{a} \left\{ ~\left[ ~\sum_{(b+1) = a-1} \frac{a-1}{q} \binom{b+1}{a-1} q^{b+1} ~\right] \\ - \left[ ~\sum_{b = a-2}^\infty \binom{b}{a-2} q^b ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{p^a}{a} \left\{ ~
\left[ ~\frac{a-1}{q} \frac{q^{a-1}}{p^a} ~\right] - 
\left[ ~\frac{q^{a-2}}{p^{a-1}} ~\right]
 ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{q^{a-2}}{a} \left[ ~(a-1) - p ~\right] = q^{a-2} - 
\left[ ~\frac{1 + p}{q^2} ~~\frac{q^a}{a} ~\right].$$
To complete the problem, I will use the identity:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = \log\left[ ~\frac{1}{1-x} ~\right] ~: ~-1 < x < 1.$$
So, the final computation is
$$\sum_{a=2}^\infty \left \{ ~q^{a-2} - 
\left[ ~\frac{1 + p}{q^2} ~~\frac{q^a}{a} ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{1-q} - 
\left\{ ~\frac{1 + p}{q^2} \times 
\left[ ~\log\left( ~\frac{1}{1-q} ~\right) - q ~\right] ~\right\}.$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum-1}}$
To Prove:
$$ \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^n = 
\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}. \tag2 $$
Throughout Addendum-1, it should be assumed that unless otherwise specified, 
$~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},~$ and that $~-1 < x < 1.$
Also, throughout Addendum-1, the expression $~0^{0}~$ is interpreted to equal $~1.$
Let $~R_k(x)~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} ~x^{n-k} .$
Let $~S_k(x)~$ denote $~\displaystyle \frac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.$
Claim 
$R_k(x) = S_k(x).$
Assuming that the claim is true, you have that
$$ \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^n = R_k(x) \times \frac{x^k}{k!} = S_k(x) \times \frac{x^k}{k!} =\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.$$
So, in Addendum-1,  it only remains to prove the claim.

Given any function $~f(x),~$ let $~f^{[m]}(x)~$ denote the $~m$-th derivative of the function $~f(x) ~: ~m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$
First, I will use induction to prove that
$~\displaystyle S_0^{[k]}(x) = S_k(x).$
For $~\mathbf{k=1}:$
$$S_0^{[1]}(x) = (-1) ~(1-x)^{-2} ~(-1) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = S_1(x).$$
For $~\mathbf{k=K+1}:$
Inductively assuming that the formula is true for $~k = K,~$ you have that
$$S_0^{[K+1]}(x) = S_K^{[1]}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\frac{K!}{(1-x)^{K+1}} ~\right]
$$
$$= K! \times (-K-1) \times (1-x)^{-K-2} ~(-1) $$
$$= \frac{(K+1)!}{(1-x)^{K+2}} = S_{K+1}(x).$$
So, by induction, it is proven that
$$S_0^{[k]}(x) = S_k(x). \tag3 $$

For $~k = 0,~$ the claim that $~R_0(x) = S_0(x)~$ is equivalent to claiming that
$$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x},$$ which is a standard formula for geometric series.
Since $~R_0(x) = S_0(x),~$ then using (3) above, you have that
$$R_0^{[k]}(x) = S_0^{[k]}(x) = S_k(x). \tag4 $$
So, it only remains to prove that
$$R_k(x) = R_0^{[k]}(x).$$

I will now prove that $~R_0^{[k]}(x) = R_k(x) ~$ by doing induction on $~k.$
For $~\mathbf{k=1}:$
Note that given any power series, where $~x~$ is inside the radius of convergence, that the power series has the property of uniform continuity.
One of the consequences of uniform continuity of a (convergent) power series is that the derivative of the infinite sum equals the infinite sum of the derivative of each of the terms.
So, since the radius of convergence of $~R_0(x)~$ is $~-1 < x < 1, ~$ you have that
$$R_0^{[1]}(x)
= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\sum_{n=0}^\infty ~x^n ~\right] 
$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{ ~\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~x^n ~\right] 
~\right\}. $$
Note that the very first term in the above summation, which represents $~n = 0,~$ equals $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~x^0 ~\right]. ~$  This equals the derivative of a constant, and so equals $~0.$
Therefore,
$$R_0^{[1]}(x) 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ ~\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~x^n ~\right] 
~\right\} $$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ ~n ~x^{n-1} ~\right] = R_1(x).$$

For $~\mathbf{k=K+1}:$
Inductively assume that
$$R_0^{[K]}(x) = R_K(x)  \implies R_0^{[K+1]}(x) = R_K^{[1]}(x).$$
By use of (4) above, as a consequence of the inductive assumption, for each $~x~$ such that $~-1 < x < 1,~$ it is being inductively assumed, by implication, that $~R_K(x) = S_K(x).$
Note that $~R_K(x)~$ is a power series, which has uniform continuity.
Further, you have that when $~-1 < x < 1,~$ that $~S_K(x)~$ is a well defined (finite) value, with $~R_K(x) = S_K(x).~$ This implies that if $~-1 < x < 1,~$ then $~x~$ is inside the radius of convergence of $~R_K(x).$
Therefore, as a consequence of the inductive assumption, the derivative of the infinite sum, represented by $~R_K(x)~$ equals the infinite sum of the derivative of each of the terms.
Therefore,
$$R_0^{[K+1]}(x) = R_K^{[1]}(x)$$
$$= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\sum_{n=K}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-K)!} ~x^{n-K} ~\right] 
$$
$$= \sum_{n=K}^\infty \left\{ ~\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\frac{n!}{(n-K)!} ~x^{n-K} ~\right] 
~\right\}.
$$
Note that the very first term in the above summation, which represents $~n = K,~$ equals $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~x^0 ~\right].~$  This equals the derivative of a constant, and so equals $~0.$
Therefore,
$$R_0^{[K+1]}(x) = R_K^{[1]}(x)
= \sum_{n=K+1}^\infty \left\{ ~\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\frac{n!}{(n-K)!} ~x^{n-K} ~\right] 
~\right\} $$
$$= \sum_{n=K+1}^\infty \left[ ~\frac{n!}{(n-K)!} ~(n-K)~x^{n - K - 1} ~\right]$$
$$= \sum_{n=K+1}^\infty \left[ ~\frac{n!}{(n-[K+1])!} ~x^{n-(K+1)} ~\right] = R_{K+1}(x).$$
So, by induction, it is proven that
$$R_0^{[k]}(x) = R_k(x). \tag5 $$
So, combining the results of (4) above and (5) above, you have that
$$R_k(x) = S_k(x),$$
so the claim is proven.

Wonderful!! Your final expression evaluated to 0.84 for P = 0.5, the result that came via simulation

Sorry for not being able to accept your solution yet. Your expression in the form of infinite series seems correct to me. I am just having a bit difficulty to understand the second lemma you used in your addendum. if that is correct then your whole solution is correct.

@user5001880 Please leave a comment confirming that you are looking for a proof that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.~$  When I receive your confirmation comment, I will add a corresponding Addendum-1 to the end of my answer, with the corresponding proof.

yes this is exactly what I was talking about

I got the proof from chatgpt. But I am still curious to know what your proof is. The one which chatgpt gave uses generalized binomial theorem for negative powers i,e, of form (1-x)^(-n)

@user5001880 Addendum-1 just added to the end of my answer to provide the requested proof.

I got an equivalent double sum by other means and the result checks out exactly in Wolfram Alpha for $p=1/2.$

@DavidK If your other means represents an alternative line of analysis, that can be applied to any value of $~p~$ such that $~0 < p < 1,~$ then I encourage you to post your own answer to the problem.  That is, any alternative line of analysis that results in a closed form formula in terms of the variable $~p~$ will be valuable.  If instead, your alternative line of analysis merely results in the same double sum that I derived, in terms of the variable $~p,~$ then your answer could then simply refer to my addendum as a completion of your answer.

Let $e_1, e_2$ denote the expected # of births to get $1$ girl child  and $2$ successive girl children respectively.
By the geometric distribution, $e_1 = \frac1{p}$
With one birth after that, either we reach $e_2$ (get two successive girls)or with probability $(1-p)$, we are back to scratch
So $e_2=  (e_1 +1) + (1-p)e_2$, which yields
$e_2 = \frac1{p}(e_1+1)$
In these # of births, we expect $(1-p)e_2$ boys
Thua the fraction of boys in the total $=(1-p):1$
and the boy:girl ratio turns out to be just $(1-p):p$
Thus if the coin is fair, $p = \frac12$,  boys:girls $=1:1$
and if $p= \frac1{10},\;\;$ boys:girls $= 9:1$

@user2661923: Well. I didn't really expect to get this result, but this is what I got !

What does your argument get for the simpler case of stopping after the first girl, if $p=1/2$? The correct answer for that case would be $\log 2$.

@abomasnow: True, the answer reflects this, I have added a few lines

@EspeciallyLime: If we stop after the first girl, with $p = \frac12, e_1 = 2$, #of boys = # of girls = 1, $b:g=1:1$

@EspeciallyLime: Am I missing something? Shouldn't it be $E(\text{ratio}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k+1}} = 1$?

Your calculation of e2 is right but that is Expected number of births to get 2 consecutive girl child. Now what you are doing is you are calculating expected number of boys and expected number of girls and dividing them. This is not same as first dividing number of boys and number of girls and then taking their expectation

Unless I'm running right into the exercise's trap, isn't the answer that the stopping condition doesn't change the expected ratio of girls?
Here is my explanation. For simplicity, consider some very large population of couples, large enough so that we can just use proportions instead of probabilities. Let $A_n$ be the number of couples which have stopped before $n$ children and $B_n$ the number of couples which want to have a $n^{th}$ child.

The number of girls born as a $n^{th}$ child is then simply $B_n * p$.
The total number of girls is the sum: $\sum B_i * p$ which is tricky to compute,
but the ratio isn't: it's just $p$.

The very mathematical version of this argument is that, for a couple, the variable:
$$
\Delta_n = \#\text{girls} - \#\text{boys} + (1 - 2p)
$$
is a Martingale. Doob's optional sampling theorem then gives that conditioning on a stopping time cannot bias the Martingale.

The problem here is that the proportion of girls in the population is not the same as the average proportion of girls in a family, because small families have a higher proportion. For example, if you stop after the first girl (with $p=1/2$) the answer is clearly greater than $1/2$ since there is a $1/2$ chance the ratio is $1$. In fact the answer for that simpler question is $\log 2\approx .693$.

I'm not really sure if we actually care about the distribution of the ratio in a single family but wouldn't the expected value be infinite then? In both your example (stop on first girl) and OP's (stop on pair of girls?) since there is a non-zero probability of having two girls giving $r=\infty$? As far as I can see, the actual interesting example is to show the counter-intuitive result with a simple martingale, but perhaps that's wrong.

I don't know what $r$ is, but the stopping time is almost surely finite. Doob's theorem applies and tells us $E(#\text{girls}-#\text{boys})=0$, but that doesn't help us work out $E(\frac{#\text{girls}}{#\text{girls}+#\text{boys}})$.

@EspeciallyLime I could be mistaken.  The way that I interpret the problem, you are being asked to compute $$E\left( ~\frac{#\text{boys}}{#\text{girls}} ~\right).$$  Anyway, this probably doesn't matter, since you can derive one ratio from another.

@EspeciallyLime user2661923 I used $r$ to denote the ratio of girls to boys inside a single family. That ratio would be infinite for families with a single girl or two girls. So the expected value of this ratio would be infinite unless the probability of these scenarios is 0. no?

@GuillaumeDehaene yes, that's why it's more informative to consider either the ratio of boys to girls, or the ratio of girls to (girls+boys), neither of which is what you might expect

I'm not sure this works. Can't we apply the same argument to the stopping criterion of having just one girl and conclude the expected number of boys and girls are the same? But I even more strongly suspect the expected number of girls in that scenario is higher - every couple has a girl, and half have no boy.

@NuclearHoagie that case is much easier. All families has some number of boys then a girl. Each family has exactly one girl. Each family has a random number of boys with mean: $E( # \text{boys} ) = \sum_{k=0} (1-p)^k p * k = 1/2 * 0 + 1/4 * 1 + 1/8 * 2 + 1/16 * 3 + ...$ which sums to 1 (the proof is a bit involved). Interestingly, you need to sum the first 10 terms to get to 0.99 so this relies quite a bit on the tail.

@GuillaumeDehaene but in that case the actual expected proportion of girls is $\log 2$.

It's simply $(1-p) : p$, as it is for all puzzles of this form.
The stopping condition doesn't affect the ratio of boys : girls, it only affects the number of children that are born. Consider this loop: the couple has a child, which is a girl with probability $p$ and a boy with probability $(1-p)$. Then they evaluate whether they want to have more children. This is the only variable they control: how many total children they have. Different stopping conditions affect the expected number of children, but do not affect $p$.
Let $N$ be the expected number of children that are born. Of those children, the expected number of girls is $p \times N$, and the expected number of boys is $(1-p) \times N$. Therefore the expected ratio of boys to girls is $((1-p)\times N) : (p \times N)$. This is equivalent to $(1-p):p$. This is the end of the puzzle; it really is that simple.
Everything else is a red herring. The stopping condition affects $N$, but not $p$. $N$ divides out in the ratio. The stopping condition does not matter.
You can't get away from this without having the children dying in unequal proportions or pre-selecting embryos (ultimately changing $p$). If the expected number of children born is $N$ and the probability of a girl is $p$, then the expected number of girls is $N \times p$.

Suppose $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and $N = 2$. The expected number of girls is $2$, not, $1$. Indeed, if $N = 2$ there are always $2$ girls, regardless of $p$.

@MartianInvader I defined $N$ as the total number of children that are born, not the total number of girls. At the point when 2 children are born, the expected number of girls is 1. How could it possibly be anything else? You seem to be objecting because the family would keep having kids if they had only 1 girl. Then why are you claiming $N = 2$? $N$ is the total number of children that are born.

Under the restrictions given, the only way a family can have 2 children is if they are both girls. If the first two children are not both girls, $N$ will be greater than 2 for that family. So your formula of expected number of girls and boys as a function of $N$ is clearly wrong, as it's wrong for $N =2$.

@MartianInvader then you misunderstand the explanation by Jounce in which N is a random variable. You are correct that $N$ is correlated with the number of girls in the family, but the average number of girls is (remarkably) still $pE(N)$. My explanation on the martingale structure of the problem might clarify this.

@MartianInvader the question asks for the expected ratio of boys to girls. That expected ratio is not a function of $N$, it is simply $(1-p) : p$. You cannot calculate any expected values by looking at $N = 2$ in isolation; you must take into account the probability that $N = 2$ as well. This is clearly 0.25 (GG), so the 2 girls when $N=2$ only contribute 0.5 to the overall expected value of girls. But no matter what $E(N)$ is, no children are killed. Therefore the expected number of girls is $p \times E(N)$, and boys is $(1-p) \times E(N)$. $E(N)$ divides out so is not important.

@JounceCracklePop I still don't understand your argument. Can you clarify exactly what $N$ is here? Does it represent the final number of children the family has, or just the situation after they have their $N^{th}$ child?

@MartianInvader I've edited the question to be more clear. $N$ is the expected value of the total number of children. Hopefully that makes it more clear why the $N=2$ case is not relevant: it's not the correct expected value. When I said it was the "total number of children born" I was thinking out of a large number of families following this policy, but the question was phrased around a single family. Note that we never have to bother calculating $N$.
